# Any built in functions to convert Datacolumn to split strings in C#.net 2.0

Tags: c#, datacolumn

I have a datacolumn, which I would like to split e.g.

ALICE 
MEGAN 
JANET

split to:
ALICE, MEGAN, JANET

I know I can do it with for loops but I'd like to know if there's any built-in functions in .Net Framework. Thanks.

**EDIT: My question is not clear. Let me try to re-articulate:**

I have a datacolumn i.e. one column of many rows of names in this context:

```
datarow[0]["name"] = ALICE
datarow[1]["name"] = MEGAN
datarow[2]["name"] = JANET
```

I'd like to know what's the most elegant way to split this column of names into a string of format:
ALICE, MEGAN, JANET

What do I need it for: I will use this format in a where clause query.

I'm using .Net C# 2.0

Answer (score 3):

```
string[] parts = "ALICE MEGAN JANET".Split();
```

Comment: The solution that you've provided does not split the values in a datacolumn. Datacolumn - by definition is one column of many rows of names in this context: row[0]["name"] = ALICE, row[1]["name"] = MEGAN, row[1]["name"] = JANET.

Answer (score 1):

Use the text.Split(new char[] {' '}) code to do this.  This method is described at:

[string.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This
```

string[] parts = "ALICE MEGAN JANET".Split(' ');

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
string[] results = dt.Rows[row_number]["col_name"].ToString().Split(' ');
```

"dt" is the DataTable object